# System.Data.SQLite Close() not releasing MemoryUsed or MemoryHighwater

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using System.Data.SQLite.dll through C# code (VS 2010) to make connection with .db database file.

In code I am making connection creating temporary tables into database and then closing the connection.
Then again I am making connection to the same database but while I am next time making connection it's still having memorystatus same as like before.

`enter code here`

string fullPath = Program.maindatabasefile;

SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + fullPath);

con.Open();

...

con.close();

con.dispose();

SQLiteConnection contemp = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + fullPath);

contemp.Open();

Here, contemp having same memorystatus as last con have.
Why it's something like this ?
is there any way to reset it ?
if we increase pagesize does it able to solve problem ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on `having same memorystatus`? What's the exact behavior you observe?

Comment: When the First connection object (con) is open it is having memorystatus - 6000

At con.close() it's memorystatus - 1000000

While contemp.open it's memorystatus - 1000000 (same as con.close())

I also put con.dispose() but still it's taking same value.

Comment: I am assuming you mean memory usage right?  If you call GC.Collect(); after the conn.Close(); and conn.Dispose() do you notice memory usage dropping?

Comment: yes, I did that. I also tried con.shutdown(). but none of works :(